# git clone --sparse on Z/OS USS causes "you have unstaged changes" error

Tags: git, zos

I am running on Z/OS Unix System Services and attempting to git clone a single directory from a repository, but am getting an "unstaged changes" error.

The cause is a `don't` in the README.md, but I don't know how to work round it. Is there a git attributes setting that I can use?

The initial command is for a sparse clone.

```
git clone --sparse https://github.com/myrepo
```

That clones and checks out the top level directory and top level files.

I cd into the cloned directory and run

```
git sparse-checkout add JustThisDir
```

To checkout out `JustThisDir`. These commands work on my MacOS laptop, but on Z/OS USS I get an error

```
error: cannot set sparse-checkout patterns: You have unstaged changes.
```

Turns out the README.md file is showing as updated, and I need to run

```
git commit -am "readme fudge"
```

before the

```
git sparse-checkout add JustThisDir
```

works.

There are other top level files in the directory, but it is only the `README.md` that shows as having untagged changes.

```
git diff
```

shows

```
-When your application needs messaging, you don’t 
+When your application needs messaging, you dont
```

The repo has `don't`, but the git copy has `dont`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone just spotted that the apostrophe in the readme didn't look right.

The fix was the change `don’t` to `don't`

Comment: I'll bet that this is because the fancy apostrophe in the source doesn't have a corresponding equivalent in EBCDIC, and was getting mangled in the clone process.